# Is there a way to cache objects with jsonapi-rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

I know we're supposed to do more research but I'm currently at a loss. I'm attempting to use fragment caching but I can't seem to find any other information out there on how to do so.

http://jsonapi-rb.org/guides/serialization/rendering.html states "cache: a cache supporting fetch_multi for fragment caching" but doesn't provide any examples on how to do it.

Comment: Are you using https://rubygems.org/gems/jsonapi-rails, right?

Comment: @SebastianPalma correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cache enabled in the current environment you're testing with, then adding it to the `cache` option should be enough:

```
# app/serializers/serializable_user.rb
class SerializableUser < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  type 'users'
  attributes :id, :name, :dob

  def jsonapi_cache_key(*)
    'cache_key'
  end
end

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render jsonapi: User.find(1), cache: Rails.cache
  end
end
```

You might want to give a look to how [this](https://github.com/jsonapi-rb/jsonapi-rails/blob/163f371fd99dc1d9efa1720b190f94c4b21a2cee/spec/render_jsonapi_spec.rb) is internally tested.

Comment: So I created a new cache instance i.e StoreCache = ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisCacheStore.new(redis: Redis.current) and passing it as an option in JSONAPI::Rails::SuccessRenderer.new.render() method. I also defined jsonapi_cache_key in the serializable object like above but how can I tell if it's actually pulling from cache?

Comment: Ok so I can see that it's pulling from cache but it's being rendered as a json string rather than an object. I'll take a look at the spec.